# Show local notification with Stream Builder

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have made a chat app with Flutter and Cloud Firestore the app is working but I need to show local notifications when a user gets a new message how can I do that.

I have used StreamBuilder to display the messages in the chat screen.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried firebase cloud messaging? There are two options to notify your phone using it. You can have a local notification which is in your app and push notifications that will display badges on your home screen and a notification badge with a number on the top right portion of your app's icon.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the data you are recieving. A stream builder may rebuild on multiple occasions including on network state change. so you can't add it directly to the build method. For example if its returning a list of items, then you can create a variable and update this variable with the length of the response. for example if the length is 5 in the first response. Update the variable to 5 and on next instance from stream you may get a 6 then check if the existing value is lesser than the current length. Then perform your custom action here (print or notification) and update the length.